# &amp; symbol not working in plugin.xml Eclipse java project. It is not showing error and also symbol is not visible in context menu

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-oxygen

I want to use & symbol in a context menu text so i have used escape character for & in plugin.xml.
I have tried all the escape characters mentioned to use & symbol like & amp; and & #38;( used space after & to show code here) but none worked for me.

```
Snippet of plugin.xml:
    <wizard
      ...
      name="Menu item where &amp; and &#38; symbol not working" ...
      ...>
    </wizard>
```

For the trial purpose i have used other symbols' escape characters like & lt; & quot; etc. and they are working fine, so there is no issues with the setup.

plugin.xml is versioned 1.0 and encoded UTF-8

Comment: On Windows & is interpreted by the operating system as an "access key" specifier and is not shown (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/about-menus#menu-access-keys)

Comment: so is there any way to show & symbol in the text?